# How to read a body from request in next13 app router

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

given get route handler:

```
export async function GET(request: Request) {
    
       // logs null
    console.log(request.body);
    
   
    return Response.json({ msg:'success' })
  
}
```

the logged body always produces null even though i included body data in my request

here is the example of a request to the route handler from the front end

```
 const res = await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/finduser', {
          data: {
                  name: 'john doe'
                }
        })
```

i also tried the request.json() but the code in catch block always run

```
 export async function GET(request: Request) {
    try{
      const res = await request.json()
      return Response.json({ res })
    } catch(e) {
      console.log('err', e)

      return Response.json({ msg:'err' })
    
    }

}
```

is there any solution or suggestion to read body data from a request?

Comment: A GET request doesn't generally have a body - https://stackoverflow.com/q/978061/3001761

Comment: export async function POST(request: Request) {

  try {
 const body = await request.json()
    console.log(body);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
    return new Response("fail")
  }

  return new Response("success")
} this code inside the caych block always returns a rejected promise what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

GET requests don't have a body. A [POST](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST) request is most likely what you're looking for.